# skip_before_filter doesn't work in inherited filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I added a filter in a parent controller. But when I try to skip the filter in the child controllers, doesn't.

```
class ParentController < ApplicationController::Base
  before_filter :hello_world

  def hello_world
    raise Exception.new "Stop the world"
  end
end

class ChildController < ParentController
  skip_before_filter :hello_world
end
```

It doesn't work. The filter always happen. If I move the before_filter to ChildController, the skip works fine.

What I'm missing? I'm working with Rails 3.0.18

Comment: Is there a reason why you are extending from `ApplicationController::Base` and not from `ApplicationController`?

Comment: @Tute did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: @matsinopoulous No, I didn't.

Comment: @Vimsha it was just an example. Nothing change if the parent is ApplicationController